# How can I adjust the thickness of the lines in rviz/path

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried parameters in .rviz file, but unfortunately failed. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393346/how-can-i-adjust-the-thickness-of-the-lines-in-rviz/path/) by [Zhou](https://answers.ros.org/users/92205/zhou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-12-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-27**:
Hi @Zhou, please take a lot at this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Zhou, please take a lot at this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines

> The scale member means different
> things for these marker types. The
> POINTS marker uses the x and y members
> for width and height respectively,
> while the LINE_STRIP and LINE_LIST
> markers only use the x component,
> which defines the line width. Scale
> values are in meters.

The marker types to POINTS, LINE_STRIP and LINE_LIST.

```
  68     // POINTS markers use x and y scale for width/height respectively
  69     points.scale.x = 0.2;
  70     points.scale.y = 0.2;
  71 
  72     // LINE_STRIP/LINE_LIST markers use only the x component of scale, for the line width
  73     line_strip.scale.x = 0.1;
  74     line_list.scale.x = 0.1;
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0